# Where to put my missing .mouseover() to get the mouse position? (jquery)

Tags: jquery, coordinates, mouseover

After some reading from [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position#How_do_I_find_the_mouse_position.3F), I have the following partly working code:

```
$(document).bind ("found_match", function(e){
 $('#status2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   });
```

When the event: "found_match happens", it should show the mouse coordinates in the div: "status2", but it doesn't. Obviously because I am missing the .mousover(). But where to put this in my code to make it work so that it wil show the mouse coordinates the moment this event happened?

Many thanks

Comment: i'm guessing found_match is a custom event you created, can we see the code for that?

Comment: @amosrivera -- the code is in the OP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#someID').mousemove(function(event){
    $(document).trigger('found_match', event);
});
```

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/M3FwY/
(I had to change the parameters of your custom function a bit)

Comment: If I add this in my script it says: undefined, undefined

Answer (score 1):

`found_match` is a [custom event](http://api.jquery.com/bind#example-6). **You, the programmer** need to `trigger` that event at some point.

```
$('#foo').mousemove(function (e)
{
    if (someCondition) // probably involving e.pageX and e.pageY
    {
        $(document).trigger('found_match');
    }
});
```